# Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, video, youtube, internet-explorer-8

Using some Jquery to do this here,

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  if($('html').hasClass('ie8')){
      $('div#videoWrapper').removeClass('visible').addCLass('hidden');
      $('div#videoWrapper_ie').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
      // do nothing so far
  }
});
```

I don't think I'm targeting this correctly with jQuery. I basically have an a youtube video in an iframe and another in the old embed method. Because there is an issue with the < iframe youtube not being supported in IE8 and lower. I Thought I could target it this way and change it. but I don't think i'm targeting it right. any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: `addCLass` looks like a typo of `addClass`.

Comment: Always include full error details ... the property mentioned in error is a big clue

Answer (score 0):

It was the typo in the addClass thanks guys, code works fine after that.